# Active Record Association--Stale State Method Definition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm going through the Ruby code of Rails and have not quite understood the following method.

The comments state the following:

> The target is stale if the target no longer points to the record(s)
>   that the relevant foreign_key(s) refers to. If stale, the association
>   accessor method on the owner will reload the target. It's up to
>   subclasses to implement the stale_state method if relevant.
>         Note that if the target has not been loaded, it is not considered stale.

And here's the definition:

```
def stale_target?
    !inversed && loaded? && @stale_state != stale_state 
end
```

The part I *didn't* get is why is it *NOT* equal to `stale_state`?

Comment: Perhaps if it is already marked as stale there is no need to do anything (?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

stale_state would be implemented in a sub_class for certain associations.  see http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveRecord/Associations/Association/stale_state

There it states

> This should be implemented to return the values of the relevant key(s) on the owner, so that when stale_state is different from the value stored on the last find_target, the target is stale.
>
> This is only relevant to certain associations, which is why it returns nil by default.

If stale_state has not been overridden in a sub_class it will return nil and be equal to @stale_state which will also be nil